# Does tonsillectomy increase the incidence of bronchitis in asthmatics as compared to sufferers of chronic Tonsillitis

Tags: asthma, tonsillitis, tonsil-tonsillectomy

Has having allergy induced asthma which can also be aggravated by intense exercise been shown to get worse after having tonsils removed in adult males?  A common treatment for repeatedly getting Angina Tonsillitis in a short space of time is to have the tonsils removed.  Has this been shown to increase the risk of catching Bronchitis in adult asthmatics?

Angina Tonsillitis severely affects an asthmatics ability to breath easily causing airways to remain aggravated restricted often resulting in the patient having to take increased medication for extended periods of time to regain normal quality of breathing.  Has Bronchitis which is often prevented by normal functioning tonsils been shown to be worse for asthmatics than tonsillitis and are they more susceptible to catching it after having their tonsils removed than before and more so than non-asthmatics?

[The following source](https://www.medindia.net/news/tonsil-and-adenoid-removal-may-up-asthma-risk-180084-1.htm) deals with and indicates there is an increased risk of COPD following tonsil and or adenoid removal but does not deal at all with the case which I am interested in, which is if the the risk increase of incidence in asthmatics is increased after a tonsillectomy as compared to subjects who already frequently get Angina Tonsillitis.

A more detailed review of the study [described here](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2018/06/180607135151.htm) breaks down the results further.  Again this does not address my question as the dataset does not sufficiently cover adult males who already suffer from asthma and are prone to getting Tonsillitis already.  I want to know if the risk of getting a COPD disease is increased after a Tonsillectomy for subjects who are already more prone than normal to getting Tonsillitis and if the increased risk of a COPD disease has been shown to have a greater negative impact on subjects measured quality of life than chronic Tonsillitis.

Even better will be any concrete results on the measure of how asthma is affected after having both diseases.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! [For a number of reasons outlined in this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748/8212), we can not, and will not, give personal medical advice. If you have a question regarding your personal health, you should see a doctor. For further information on how this site is supposed to work, what is on-topic or not, you can take the [tour], visit the [ask] page and [meta]. I have voted to close this question and [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question) explains question closure.

Comment: As you seem to know that personal medical advice is strictly off-topic: please [edit] out all personalised info and add some prior research on of your own, which is also required here. A generalised question might work, the current approach chosen does not.

Comment: Aesir, please heed LangLang's request. When you've completed the edits and the question is a general question useful to others and it demonstrates some prior research, I will reopen it.

Comment: I re-worded the question.  I am not sure how I can show prior research without being able to provide specific information.  As my prior research has involved talking to medical professionals and as is often the case with conditions like asthma highly individual.  I don't think however that warrants the question as not suitable.  As an asthma sufferer and not an educated medical professional there is not enough public information available on this topic, hence asking here.

Comment: Asking multiple questions at once is frowned upon, and your title openly asked for advice, so I made some additional edits and reopened the question. You're always free to ask your other questions separately.

Comment: I am voting to put this question on hold because despite many requests for evidence of prior research, none has been provided.

Comment: Uh come on.  Your comment isn't helpful.  I have stated that there is an issue with providing 'prior evidence' as there isn't much information on the topic.  I have also stated that there is no clear outline for how to provide proof of prior evidence when there isn't much available.  Your comment does nothing to provide help to make the question for the site better.  If you want to vote for it to be put on hold fine.  I get this site seems to be completely totalitarian in how a question must be asked.

Comment: But it can happen that there aren't good sources of information related to a questions topic and asking these to be provided is an exercise in futility. The issue needs to be addressed about why a question is not considered good enough, when it addresses a topic that isn't well covered by existing sources of information.  That in my opinion is why a question should be asked.  Not "hey here is my question" please give me a link to some information which already exists.  I wish to collect answers based on knowledge from people in a field I do not have experience in.

Comment: I do not understand why that is a bad format for this website, nor how the point of building a community which basically says.  If you can't find existing information on your question, it isn't worth asking.  If I could find existing information on the topic, the question wouldn't need to be asked.  The guide to how to ask a question in this community needs serious work to address these shortcomings, if they are such an issue.

Comment: Feedback for why something should be put on hold should be addressed more clearly for a new contributer than in just a comment.  As so far the user experience of this site which clearly does contain knowledgeable people is not very easy to understand and the short comments which do not elaborate enough detail about why something is a bad fit, only waste everyones time.     I want to improve my question so it fits this site.  At the moment I cannot as I do not understand how to.  If you would like to help and address the issue, great.  But the onus should be on the community to say how and why.

Comment: Have you tried just googling the new question title? We want to enforce users having searched on their own, even if it's just a little bit, before coming here. That title as search string gives ample hits, some very relevant, some less so. Read a few, pick one or two and add your understanding of them into the question; if you have trouble understanding what you found, *that's* where we want to help.

Comment: @Aesir I reopened your question following our edits despite the fact that the question was a request for medical advice to begin with and you added no additional research. I did so in an effort to be inclusive, but I'm beginning to wonder if that was a mistake. If you want to discuss site policy, please head to meta. In the time you've spent adding comments here you could have found the answer to the question contained in the title, as LangLang has pointed out.

Comment: I will discuss this further in the meta.  It is good the question was re-opened however it caused a lot of confusion about what is acceptable and what is not.  It did not feel welcoming or inclusive experience.  Searching the title indeed does return results, however they do not answer my question sufficiently.  I would not have asked a question if it was possible to find the answer myself, as there would be no point.  It seems to be a very chicken and egg scenario you are trying to enforce with this website and I cannot see how you expect to grow a community as it currently is.